# I need to save all .xlsx files in one folder, into another folder

Tags: python, excel, automation

I think I can do this using python, but I'm not sure.

I have a bunch of .xlsx files in a folder (call it User/Data/Input) and I need to save all of them into a different folder (call it User/Data/Output).

Instead of having to open each excel file from the Input folder, and then save it to the Output folder manually, I'd like a program that can do that for me. I do not need to change the workbook names when this occurs, I just need them to be saved in the output folder.

Thanks!

Comment: You can do it in your shell. Is this windows? `xcopy User\Data\Input\*.xlsx User\Data\Output`.

Answer (score 0):

```
shutil.copy(src, dst)
```

From the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html)
"Copy the file src to the file or directory dst. If dst is a directory, a file with the same basename as src is created (or overwritten) in the directory specified. Permission bits are copied. src and dst are path names given as strings."